# Center Text in Table column

Tags: html, css

How to center text in `<td>`?

I tried:

```
<style>
.float_center {
    float: right;    
    position: relative;
    left: -50%; /* or right 50% */
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

And as result I got, see below image.

[image]

For full refrence:

```html
<script src="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/users/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/users/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/users/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Invoice</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <center><button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onClick="window.print()">Print</button></center>

            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        .float_center {
          float: right;
          position: relative;
          left: -50%;
          /* or right 50% */
          text-align: left;
        }
      </style>
      <table id="myHeader" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <h1><span class="float_center">Company</span></h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <h1><span class="float_center">Number</span></h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <h3><span style="float: left;">Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <h3><span style="float: right;">Date</span></h3>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Sr.</th>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
            <td><strong>400</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>


    </div>


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include only the **relevant** part of your code, and tidy it so it can be easier to read. And does the image show what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ammarx, No image does not show what I want to acheive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `text-center` default bootstrap class to center text in `h1` and also no need to add `span` tag in `h1`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <center>
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
                </center>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="myHeader" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <h1 class="text-center">Company</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <h1 class="text-center">Number</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3><span style="float: left;">Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3><span style="float: right;">Date</span></h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
                <td><strong>400</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: May I get the explanation, what you skipped and added in my code?

Comment: ya, sure.. remove your `float_center` class from `h1 span` , also remove span for h1 and add `text-center` class in `h1` tag

Comment: I just tried `span` instead of `h1` and I didn't get the result, why so? And how to get the result in that situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

in `.float_center` instead of what you currently have.

Here:

```html
<script src="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/users/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/users/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/users/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://whspr.epizy.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Invoice</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <center><button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onClick="window.print()">Print</button></center>

            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        .float_center {
          display: block;
          text-align: center;
        }
      </style>
      <table id="myHeader" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <h1><span class="float_center">Company</span></h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <h1><span class="float_center">Number</span></h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <h3><span style="float: left;">Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <h3><span style="float: right;">Date</span></h3>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Sr.</th>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
            <td><strong>400</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>


    </div>


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer also works but I went for, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150514/8835762

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align: center`

```html
<button onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center">
      Company
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center">
      Number
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span>Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span>Date</span></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
      <td><strong>400</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer also works but I went for, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150514/8835762

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to the inline style

```
style="text-align: center";
```

But if you are using bootstrap, then just simply add a bootsrap class

```
class="text-center"
```

Answer (score -2):

Directly write

```
   h1 {text-align: center;}
```

in your `<style>` tag and remove `float_center` class styling
**

- Using Flex:

Or edit your `.float_center` class

```
<style>
        .float_center {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;  
        }

      </style>
```

Comment: I would also downvote if I can. There is no property in `float` as `center`. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: I  know about that  I was mentioning about  your float_center class Edited my answer try it